# Pass vector<vector<float> > from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, vector

I am calling a Python module from C++ module. In my C++ module I have a `vector<vector<float>> data(size)`
Now, i want to pass this to python where I will be doing some manipulations onto it.
I see that the command `PyFloat_FromDouble` returns a `PyObject` and converts double to float. Now, I want my data to be in float and I get the result in `PyObject` form which I can further pass to python by `PyTuple_SetItem`.

Does anyone knows how to pass a `vector<vector<float> >` to Python from C++. I am able to pass a 1D `vector<double>` to Python from C++ but need to pass 2D vector.

Comment: 2D - so make a tuple of tuples?

Comment: Thanks Nayuki. But I don't know how will it work. Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: As far as I am able to understand there is no direct way for this. We should break the 2-D vector into 2 1-D vectors and pass them all one by one. Just a guess. Woking on implementing it.

Comment: Tuple of tuples is very time and memory consuming. Is there any other way?